# Better way of filtering multiple checkboxes php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to make a php , mysql simple check box filter.
[image]

So there are 3 sections of checkboxes and user need to select atleast any one of each for result to display.

My code

```
if(isset($_POST['cse'])){ $cse=1;} else $cse=0;
    if(isset($_POST['ee'])){ $ee=2;} else $ee=0;
    if(isset($_POST['me'])){ $me=3;} else $me=0;

    if(isset($_POST['btech'])){ $btech=1;} else $btech=0;
    if(isset($_POST['mtech'])){ $mtech=2;} else $mtech=0;
    if(isset($_POST['phd'])){ $phd=3;} else $phd=0;

    if(isset($_POST['y2014'])){ $y2014=14;} else $y2014=0;
    if(isset($_POST['y2015'])){ $y2015=15;} else $y2015=0;
    if(isset($_POST['y2016'])){ $y2016=16;} else $y2016=0;
    if(isset($_POST['y2017'])){ $y2017=17;} else $y2017=0;
    if(isset($_POST['cg'])){$cg=test_input($_POST['cg']);} else $cg=0;



if($cse!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}}


if($cse!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($cse!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($cse!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}


if($cse!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}


if($cse!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($cse!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($cse!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($cse!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($cse!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($cse!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($cse!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$cse AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}




if($me!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($me!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($me!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($me!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}


if($me!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}


if($me!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($me!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($me!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($me!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($me!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($me!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($me!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$me AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($ee!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($ee!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($ee!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($ee!=0 && $btech!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$btech AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}


if($ee!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}


if($ee!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($ee!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($ee!=0 && $mtech!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$mtech AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}



if($ee!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2014!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2014 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($ee!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2015!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2015 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($ee!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2016!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2016 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}

if($ee!=0 && $phd!=0 && $y2017!=0){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tnp_users WHERE branch=$ee AND batch=$phd AND year=$y2017 AND cgpa>=$cg";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $entry_no=$row['entry_no'];
        echo "<tr><td> " . $row["entry_no"]."</td><td contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",0)'>" . $row["cgpa"]."</td><td contenteditable='true'  onBlur='saveToDatabase(this.innerHTML,".$row["user_id"].",1)' >".$row["strikes"]."</td></tr>";
    }

}
}
```

Now i manually made all the cases what the user can do , in my approach there is a lot of repetition and also if the no of checkboxes increase it will be very difficult to count all the cases

Comment: That is too much code for us to look through, I would suggest that you simplify what you're trying to ask.

Comment: use javascript along with php :) that would be easier :)  write an on click function which passes the checkbox values to some var in js. Then use an ajax which will include the url of your php function along with data. then process the data and on success function append your result :)

Comment: @Scuzzy it is all the possible cases like if the user has selected "cse and 2017 and btech"

Comment: this is bad db design, I think you should rethink this. You may want to use classes / methods for this, or a case.

Comment: How many permutations are there?

Comment: @Strawberry 24 , but will increase a lot for more checkboxes

Comment: Well until it gets to 1000 times that figure, I’d handle the whole thing in php/JavaScript

Comment: @Strawberry I have lot of if statements and sql queries for each of them will it make any difference in site speed?

Comment: You should have 1 query only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a feeling something is getting over complicated somewhere.

I'm going to focus on just this statement...

> So there are 3 sections of checkboxes and user need to select atleast any one of each for result to display.

In this example, I've got three sets of checkboxes `category[branch]`, `category[batch]` and `category[year]`. By not selecting an item in the set, the post variable doesn't exist and pass the `isset()` and `count()` validations.

> **/ ! \ THIS CODE IS NOT SQL INJECTION SAFE**

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  if( isset( $_POST['category'] ) === true and count( $_POST['category'] ) === 3 )
  {
    $category = array_keys( $_POST['category'] );
    $selections = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $_POST['category']);
    $where = array();
    foreach( $_POST['category'] as $key => $value )
    {
      $where[] = $key . " IN ('" . implode("','",$value)."') ";
    }
    echo 'three areas selected; ' . implode( ', ', $category );
    echo 'you selected: ' . implode( ', ', $selections );
    echo 'WHERE ' . implode( ' AND ', $where );
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'please select atleast any one of each category';
  }
}

?>
<form method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[branch][]" value="cse">cse
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[branch][]" value="ee">ee
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[branch][]" value="me">me
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[batch][]" value="btech">btech
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[batch][]" value="mtech">mtech
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[batch][]" value="phd">phd
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[year][]" value="y2014">y2014
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[year][]" value="y2015">y2015
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[year][]" value="y2016">y2016
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[year][]" value="y2017">y2017
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[year][]" value="cg">cg
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: how do i query through mysql for the selected ones , my method is making all the cases and checking which is tedious

Comment: I'll do up another example with more than three selections, showing how to get a set of three categories.

Comment: Please review my edit, I've aligned it closer to what you're expecting I think. The users can select multiple from each of the three categories is that correct? if its not then simply change to a radio button interface or drop down to limit it to one per category. When you say "_select atleast any one_" you imply one is the minimum, but you can pick more than one.

Comment: this is fine but i need to sql query for the selected ones , which is what i am stuck at

Comment: `$_POST['category']` is an array of what's been selected by the user neatly categorized. I can't help any more because I feel you're missing some key fundamentals of PHP, I'm not going to comment further on SQL injection, but please review my final update, you can now see I am building a WHERE clause in the format of `branch IN ('me') AND batch IN ('mtech') AND year IN ('y2014') ` from the data in `$_POST['category']`.

This approach allows more complex selecting to occur: `branch IN ('cse','ee') AND batch IN ('phd') AND year IN ('y2015','y2016') `

Comment: i know about sql injection , but as this is for a admin panel i am ignoring it, i didn't knew about IN in sql , thank you it helped my issue :)

Comment: That's good to hear, I hope your project goes well.